# My 2004 manual Renault Clio is not going above 30 kmh and sometimes goes to 60 kmh

Tags: acceleration, renault, clio

Okay so this happens like almost every summer/ spring . My car suddenly won't move. I can shift gears normally . It just won't go past 30 kmh or 60 kmh and if it goes it starts to slow down and not take any gas . Anyone might know the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is the check engine light on?  It could be a number of things - clogged fuel filter, bad fuel pump, dirty Mass Airflow sensor, dirty engine air filter, malfunctioning Throttle Position Sensor.  There are other potential causes, but these are the ones I would check first.

Comment: Diesel or petrol?